# How to find all matches instead of the last match in look ahead and look behind in preg_match_all()

Tags: php, regex, repeat, preg-match-all

I have this text.

```
*s*
*q: what is 3+3? *.
*o: 3 *.
*o: 4 *.
*o: 6 *.
*e*

*s*
*q: what is 4*4? *.
*o: 7 *.
*o: 12 *.
*o: 16 *.
*e*

*s*
*q: what is 10/2? *.
*o: 1 *.
*o: 5 *.
*e*
```

I wrote the following expression in php `preg_match_all()`

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\*s\*)[\s\S\d\D\w\W](?=\*e\*e)/", $str, $matches);
```

But the regex matches from first `*s*` to the last `*e*` and skips the middle `*s*` and `*e*`.
how can I get the repeating sets. I want three sets from this regex.

Comment: pls write exactly what you expect

Comment: Try adding the "ungreedy" option: `preg_match_all('/(?<=\*s\*)[\s\S\d\D\w\W]+(?=\*e\*)/U', $str, $matches);` - note I also modified your original expression likely a typo (quantifier on character class).

Comment: @B__ It works. but it finds only the first string.

Comment: Try it on the tester: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/EAt#tab-preg-match-all .

Answer (score 1):

Your code would not behave as you describe, so I start off with the modified regex (differences lost due to clerical copy error ?)

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\*s\*)[\s\S\d\D\w\W]+(?=\*e\*)/", $str, $matches);
```

Your regex is matching greedily, ie. tries to find the *longest* string in your input that matches the pattern. As you observed, this would be the entire content.

In order to get the desired result, be more specific in your pattern and use:

```
/(?<=\*s\*[\r\n])(\*.*\*\.[\r\n]+)+/
```

The Lookbehind now refers to the `*s*` initiating a block including the newline character. The remainder of the expression denotes an arbitrary number of consecutive lines starting with a `*` and ending with `*.`. Thsi behavior hinges on the `.*` pattern *not* matching line termination characters, which is the default

Note that this cuts off before matching a line containing `*e*` as it does not end with the `.` character.

Also note that you might have to modify the lookbehind portion filling in the newline character (sequence) of your file.

No trailing lookahead portion is needed.

Check the matching with [this example on Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/9V8WEF/1).

Comment: *'clerical copy error'* ! It's always the same.

Comment: You might also write it without any lookarounds using a capture group `\*s\*\R((?:\*.*\*\.\R)+)\*e\*` https://regex101.com/r/9MSBd4/1

Comment: It is not working in preg_match_all() in my file.